# Powershell - Disable and move users to a new OU

Tags: powershell, foreach

brand new member here..

I'm trying to create a powershell script that can create a new OU with the current date (dd-MM-yyyy), disable users from a text file and then move them to the newly created OU.

So far I have gotten everything but the move to work. I've read that it might be because the text file contains the users `sAMAccountName`, which doesn't work with `Move-ADObject`?

Just for the record I'm pretty new to scripting in general, and I know the last line is completely off. Everything has been composed of stuff I have found online.

Code:

```
$OU = "$((get-date).toString('dd-MM-yyyy'))"
$PathOU = "OU=DEPARTURES,OU=IT,OU=USERS,OU=DK,DC=xxx"

New-ADOrganizationalUnit $OU -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false -Path $PathOU

$CN = get-content "\\Server\User Administration\User Deletion\UsersToBeDisabled.txt"
$CN |Foreach {
Get-ADUser $_ | Disable-ADAccount
Move-ADObject -Identity $_ -TargetPath $OU
}
```

Error:

> Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'firstname.lastname' under: 'DC=xxx'.
>   ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject**

I hope you have some ideas on how to get this to work, thanks!

BR. Mik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-PassThru` switch with `Disable-ADAccount` to hand your user object along the pipline to `Move-ADObject`

```
Get-ADUser $_ | Disable-ADAccount -PassThru | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$OU,$PathOU"
```

Alternative this should work as well:

```
$user = Get-ADUser $_ 
$user | Disable-ADAccount 
$user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$OU,$PathOU"
```

Comment: That seems to get me a bit further, but I still get an error.. Hmm.
The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Does changing the order work? Get-ADUser $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OU  -PassThru | Disable-ADAccount

Comment: What does Get-ADUser $_ return?

Comment: The following information:
DistinguishedName : CN="users description from AD",OU=DEPARTURES,OU=IT,OU=USERS,OU=DK,OU=Countries,DC=xxx
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : "firstname"
Name              : "users description from AD"
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : "long id"
SamAccountName    : "firstname.lastname"
SID               :  "long id"
Surname           : "users last name"
UserPrincipalName : "users email address"

Comment: Which PowerShell version do you use?

Comment: I use version 5.1.14393.2430
As for the alternative solution, sadly the same error.. It's not happy about the move.

Comment: The TargetPath for Move-ADObject should be: -TargetPath "OU=$OU,$PathOU". I sadly did not see that.

Comment: You're a legend! :) Appreciate it.
For the record the alternative solution, works!

Answer (score 0):

Couple mistakes here;

1- you're trying to use the entire AD object for the -identity flag: instead of $_ try using $_.samaccountname.

2- you're trying to move-adobject to $ou which is merely a string. I'm assuming your new-adOrganizationalUnit command works; so add a line after that to say "$newOU = Get-ADorganizationalunit" -path [whatever]

Sorry I don't have time to type out & test :(